# Borrar la última línea de un txt con un .bat

Tags: batch

tengo un txt generado desde Qlik Sense. El asunto con este archivo es que al transformarlo a txt se crea con una línea en blanco en el primer y último registro. Ya logré eliminar la primera línea en blanco con una solución que encontré acá mismo en Stackoverflow... ahora mi problema es eliminar la última línea :c con ayuda de un archivo .bat

¿Alguna solución?

Mi archivo se parece a esto:

```
-----------------------------------------
                         <- línea en blanco
sdafghfgcdg2345345
dfgfhfgh4545456456
fhfghjfghfgh567574
jhgjfghfghfhfhj888
hghjhjkjkljljkl987
                         <- línea en blanco
-----------------------------------------
```

con la solución que ya encontré falta eliminar la última línea

```
-----------------------------------------
sdafghfgcdg2345345
dfgfhfgh4545456456
fhfghjfghfgh567574
jhgjfghfghfhfhj888
hghjhjkjkljljkl987
                         <- línea en blanco
-----------------------------------------
```

Como debe quedar:

```
-----------------------------------------
sdafghfgcdg2345345
dfgfhfgh4545456456
fhfghjfghfgh567574
jhgjfghfghfhfhj888
hghjhjkjkljljkl987
-----------------------------------------
```

Mil gracias.

Comment: ¿cómo es la primer solución que encontraste?

Comment: @ChristopherVilla  

La solución que encontré fue esa adaptada a mi necesidad de archivo:

`@echo on

cd C:\ROLLUP\DESARROLLO\FDN\4_Qvd_Modelo

type Formato351.txt

pause

for /F "skip=1 tokens=*" %%i in (Formato351.txt) do @echo %%i >> 

Formato351_Final.txt
pause
echo se ha modificado el archivo
DEL Formato351.txt
REN Formato351_Final.txt Formato351.txt
type Formato351.txt`

Comment: Deberías poner ese comentario como respuesta y aceptarla, para dejar la pregunta marcada como respondida. Otra opción sería usar VBS ;)

Answer (score 1):

Del texto que quieres formatear, ahora te falta eliminar la sexta línea, así que te funcionará si a la solución que encontraste modificas el número en la línea que empieza:

`for /F "skip=1 tokens` ...

Y pones 6 en vez de uno. Entonces al copiar el archivo se esquivará la sexta línea